# Java 8 for Linux x64 has no libnpjp2.so?

Tags: java, firefox, plugin

I downloaded Java 8 Update 281 for Linux x64 from https://www.java.com/en/download/ and installed it on my machine. However, when I tried to enable this java in browser, I cannot find the file `libnpjp2.so` that used to be present in the lib/amd64 folder.

I used to create a symbolic link to this file in the Firefox plugins folder:

`sudo ln -s  /usr/lib/jvm/jre<version>/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libnpjp2.so`

This file existed until at least Java 8 Update 181. How should one install the plugin now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java Plugin was removed in Java 8 Update 271.

From the Java 8 Update 271 (8u271) [release notes](https://java.com/en/download/help/release_changes.html):

> **Removed Feature:** Java Plugin is Removed from JDK 8u for Linux, Solaris, and MacOS Platforms
> NPAPI is considered to be a vulnerable plugin and has been disabled in many browsers. No browsers currently support Java Plugin, which is NPAPI-based, on Linux, Solaris, and MacOS platforms.
>
> Starting from 8u271, the part of Java Plugin responsible for integration and interaction with a browser (in particular libnpjp2 library) and an associated artifact will not be built and is not part of the JRE distribution on Linux, Solaris, and MacOS platforms.
> JDK-8240210 (not public)