# No Java Plugin? Now what?

Tags: ubuntu, java, chrome, plugin

Many systems, in particular various platforms offering a software KVM, have a Java-based UI for management.  Often these provide a URL to download a "jnlp" file.

These days Oracle et al have decided to remove this feature from the JRE package.
Ref: [Java 8 for Linux x64 has no libnpjp2.so?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639464/java-8-for-linux-x64-has-no-libnpjp2-so)
Ref: https://java.com/en/download/help/release_changes.html

How is one supposed to launch these tools (not the least of which being the ILO UI of Oracle servers) without the Java plugin now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JRE package includes a `bin/javaws` binary. That is the "Java Web Start", which takes the `*.jnlp` file and can download and run the applet.

You just need to make sure the `javaws` of an appropriate version of Java is associated with `*.jnlp` files (MIME type `application/x-java-jnlp-file`) in your browser and/or desktop environment, and the browser will be able to use the `javaws` binary to "open" the JNLP file.

The only practical difference might be that the ILO console UI opens in a separate window, rather than being embedded into the browser's window using an old and vulnerable browser plugin API designed for Netscape Navigator browser back in the 1990s.

If you use self-signed certificates for your ILO remote consoles, you may also have to set up a security exception to trust the certificate both in the web browser and in the JRE. The latter can be done using the Java Control Panel, which is available as `bin/jcontrol` in the JRE package.

This separation of the console client from the browser even allows you to run a 64-bit browser and still use a 32-bit Java JRE to run the console application. This turned out to be important for me, as I once had to get the "virtual CD-ROM" functionality working with a server that had a really old ILO version: the virtual CD-ROM function only worked with 32-bit Java.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using the Oracle Java JRE + setting up "alternatives", adding the exception and in stead of adding the mime tipes I just download the Java web app and launch it from the terminal, which is fine for the 3 times a year I need this kind of functionality.